# Shortcut for vibrate activation on iPhone

Tags: iphone, vibrate

I've just switched from Android to iPhone and there is something I'm missing: is there a way to get a shortcut in the notifications or control center to switch vibrate on and off ?

I don't want to go to Settings>Sounds> but access this directly

Answer (score 4):

There is no such shortcut available on iOS.

The closest thing to it is the mute button on the side of the iPhone.
You can disable the vibration on mute.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, but you know sometime you want it vibrate on silence, sometime no, sometime vibrate on ring, sometime no ... Is there any third party app which could enable something like that since app can have a panel in the notification center ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not how Apple sees apps on iOS. Apps have to influence on the controller center (for the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, enable assistive touch under general, accessibility.  This small white dot is always on the screen, and can be moved around.  Touch it, then go to control center, device.  You can mute or unmute.